# Ngx-datatable - Filtered data removed on row value update

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ngx-datatable

I'm using ngx-datatable 12.0.0 on Angular CLI 6.0.2 with table rows being populated from Firebase Real-Time Database (firebase 5.0.3).

When I filter the table data and edit some row values stored in Firebase, ngx-datatable removes filtered data and redirects to the first page of the table.

You can see the behaviour reproduced in Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nyqcuk

The steps to reproduce are as below:

1. Click Reset Data to set the baseline data in Firebase
2. Filter by name John
3. Click Edit Data
4. You're redirected to the first page of the table with unfiltered data.

Repeat the same steps to reproduce again.

Any idea about this behaviour ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved filtering directly on the observable.